# JavaScript Array Index Insertion when out of index

Tags: javascript, arrays

How could I insert an array of items into an existing array if the start index is outside the bounds of the array I'm inserting.

For example:

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

I need to insert at index 10.  I tried something like this:

```
Array.prototype.splice.apply(curData, [newData[0].index, 0].concat(newData));
```

but it respected the array bounds.  This COULD be accomplished with a for loop but i'd say it wouldn't be very performant at all.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What's the real world use case?

Comment: Table row virtualization when I only have partials results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arrOne = [1, 2, 3];

arrTwo = [10, 11, 12, 13];

arrOne[9] = undefined;

arrOne.concat(arrTwo);
```

Comment: Might want to use `undefined` instead.